# How to add slick slider to magento 2 product grid

Tags: magento2

I have a added a product grid to magento 2 homepage. I need to slide the product using slick slider 
[image]

Comment: did you get a chance to look at my answer ? At least comment working Or Not!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download `Slick` JS and CSS, You can download it from https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Put Your CSS `slick.css` at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/web/css/

and JS `slick.min.js` at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/web/js/

Add Your CSS at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
      <css src="Magento_Theme::css/slick.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Now you need to create a new file `requirejs-config.js` at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js

with following content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            slick:'Magento_Theme/js/slick.min'
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can use slick JS anywhere by following code:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'slick'
    ], function ($, script) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slick-class').slick({
              infinite: true,
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              autoplay: true
            });
        });
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

**Note:**

1. You need to change class name
2. Flush cache
3. deploy content if in production mode