# How to add Slick Slider

Tags: xml, phtml, cms-block, home-page, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to add slick slider on my home page in magento using static block and phtml with rotating images. if anyone have idea about that then please answer my question as soon as possible.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293808/how-to-add-slick-slider-to-magento-2-product-grid/293842#293842

Answer (score 1):

Before ask you should search a bit! There a lot of topics related slick slider work with magento2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use in you custom module or theme ?

Please follow link to have slick slider https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-slick-carousel/

Or you can attach screenshot for your code so that it would help to resolve your issue.