# How to connect my custom js slick.min.js files with requirejs-config.js?

Tags: requirejs-config.js

I need to make a slider for related-products. In order to override the template copied: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme name}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml.`

there is a code inside items.phtml:

```
<script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","jquery/jquery-migrate","slick"],function($) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("#related").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
                    slide: 'li',
                    dots: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 2500,
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 4
                });
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Now I wanted to pull the slick plugin code from the items.phtml file into a separate js file and include them via `requirejs-config.js`.

**my `requirejs-config.js` file** :

```
const config = {
    paths: {
        script: "Magento_Catalog/js/script/slider",
        'slick': "Magento_Catalog/js/slick/slick.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'slick': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery/jquery-migrate']
        }
    }
};
```

The project structure:

[image]

My custom js file is `script/slider.js` with slick code.

**How can I connect my custom slider.js and slick.min.js files with** `requirejs-config.js`?

above I indicated how I am trying to connect them in `equirejs-config.js` , but this is unsuccessful.

Comment: please look at : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293808/how-to-add-slick-slider-to-magento-2-product-grid/293842#293842

Answer (score 0):

Your `require-config` file looks fine, just one thing need to add, you have used `script` change it's name and use in quotation. Also add `shim` dependency for your slider file, like this:

```
const config = {
    paths: {
        'slider_script': "Magento_Catalog/js/script/slider",
        'slick': "Magento_Catalog/js/slick/slick.min"
    },
    shim: {
        'slick': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery/jquery-migrate']
        },
        'slider_script': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery/jquery-migrate']
        }
    }
};
```

2nd issue that could effect your slider is, you have used `not()` function when adding slick, please try to use slick function directly. And instead of `not` you can add new check like this:

```
<script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","jquery/jquery-migrate","slick"],function($) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                if(!jQuery("#related").hasClass("slick-initialized"){
                jQuery("#related").slick({
                    slide: 'li',
                    dots: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 2500,
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 4
                });
                }
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Hope this will help