# How to load slick carousel , or any other js file into magento 2?

Tags: magento2, requirejs, slick

I'm trying to load the slick carousel into my magento theme and it generates a huge error: "Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module". I think it must be related to require js, so I tried to add the following line of code to my require js, but it didn't solve the problem. How can I solve it?

[image]

The code I added:

```
 var config = {
paths: {  
        
        'slick': "Magento_Theme/js/slick/slick.min"
    },   
shim: {
    'slick': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

my default_head_blocks (head)

```
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" />
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" />
        <script src="requirejs/require.js" />
        <script src="mage/polyfill.js" />
        <script src="js/slick.min.js"/>



        <css src="mage/calendar.css" />

        <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <css src="css/slick.css" />

        <css src="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"/>

        <css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" src_type="url" />

    </head>
```

Comment: please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293808/how-to-add-slick-slider-to-magento-2-product-grid/293842#293842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add like above. You just need to add slick.min.js file in path app/design/frontend/PackageName/theme/web/js/

After that you just need to call jquery like below. You don't need to define anywhere. Please remove your code from requirejs-config.js file

```
require(['jquery',"mage/url",'mage/validation','js/slick.min'], function ($,url) {
    jQuery('.best-seller-items').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000
    });
});
```

Also please upload slick.css file in path app/design/frontend/PackageName/theme/web/css/

> Call above css file in path app/design/frontend/PackageName/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/slick.css"/>
        <script src="js/script.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**You can also put above jQuery code in file script.js which needs to be create in path app/design/frontend/PackageName/theme/web/js/**

Your slider will work with above code.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, the error continues

Comment: This is practically implemented in magento 2.4 as well. It should work. Might be you are doing somewhere wrong. Please show me your whole steps and code.

Comment: I'm using magento 2.3.5-p2, as soon as I add the file to default_head_blocks it generates an error

Comment: Which file you are adding in default_head_blocks.xml file

Comment: Can you please show me your code?

Comment: I added the default_head_blocks code. The error simply appears when I put or slick.js

Comment: You don't need to call slick.js in default_head_blocks. Please only add the code as per i have shown

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Tried, thank you very much worked. you deserved the best answer

Answer (score 0):

create the **requirejs-config.js** in your theme below path,

path : **app/design/frontend/[theme_name]**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'slick': "js/slick/slick.min"
    } ,
    shim: {
        'slick': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

and add the **slik.min.js** in path : **app/design/frontend/[theme_name]/web/js**

add the Your custom.js in below path,

path : **app/design/frontend/[theme_name]/web/js**

```
require(['jquery','slick'], 
  function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.best-seller-items').slick({
            //your code
        })
    });
 });
```

**After run the below commnds,**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f --language_code
php bin/magento c:f
```